# Data collection during several runs

Tags: anylogic

I have to run a stochastic model several times with different random numbers at each run. I have to gather data from the model like the proportion of time a ressource is seized or the average number of agents in queue for service.

I thought I would have to use a Monte Carlo experiment, but it is  not available for PLE. Can I use a parameter variation experiment to get those informations? How do i collect the data from each run and where do I store that said data? I am quite lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter variation as follows:

1. Create a parameter in your model called "dummy" as an integer
2. In your parameter variation experiment add a dataset element (or a statistics element works also maybe) called "dataset"
3. Let's imagine you want to analyze a variable called "output" that exists in your model
4. In the parameter variation experiment make the dummy parameter change from 1 to 1000 for example (1000 iterations)
5. Change the random number generation to random seed
6. Use replications if you want
7. After each simulation run do `dataset.add(root.output);`
8. You can export the data to excel `excelFile.writeDataSet(dataset, sheet, row,column);`

And that's it, you have a monte carlo experiment.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough for all your help Felipe! You are impressive!